# How to concatenate the data on one line instead of two?

Tags: vb.net

I spend a lot of time at the office manually combining latitudes and longitudes to paste into a program that locates our customers and sets up for repairs.

As an example... I copy this from the customers information page:

```
43.481075
CPE LON
-84.787613
```

I then manually modify it to look like:

```
43.481075 -84.787613
```

I'm attempting to come up with some code that will do this for me. the problem I'm encountering is, no matter what I try the latitude and longitude always end up on separate lines

```
43.481075
-84.787613
```

I've tried removing vblf,vbcrlf and vbnewline before combining the strings "lat" and  "lon". I've tried using lat & lon,   lat + lon, latlon = String.Concat(lat, " ", lon) and in my last attempt, I used stringbuilder to try and concatenate. It always gives both on separate lines. What am I missing?

Here's my latest version:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Public c As Integer
    Public lastlat As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Copy string to format from clipboard
        Dim strClipText As String = Clipboard.GetText

        ' Remove CPE LON from String
        Dim clean As String = strClipText.Replace("CPE LON", "")
        strClipText = clean

        strClipText = Replace(strClipText, vbLf, "")
        strClipText = Replace(strClipText, vbCrLf, "")
        strClipText = Replace(strClipText, vbNewLine, "")

        'Get string length
        Dim length As Integer = strClipText.Length

        ' Find minus sign (Start of Longitude)
        For c1 = 1 To length - 1
            Dim cchk As Char = strClipText(c1)
            If cchk = "-" Then
                c = c1
                lastlat = c1 - 1
            End If
        Next

        Dim lastc As Integer = length - 1
        Dim cchk1 As String = strClipText(lastc)
        Dim lat As String = strClipText.Substring(0, lastlat)
        Dim lon As String
        Dim lon1 As String
        For curc = c To lastc
            lon1 = strClipText(c)
            lon = lon & lon1
            c = c + 1
        Next

        Dim builder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(lat)
        Dim llen As Integer = lat.Length
        builder.Insert(llen, lon)
        Dim latlon As String = builder.ToString()

        Clipboard.Clear()
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(latlon)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: that didn't post right. the original data is on 3 lines to start, and everything I've tried, the latitude and longitude always ends up on 2 line

Comment: Did you ever think to actually examine the original text to see EXACTLY what it contains?  Look at each character specifically to see what it is and where the line break might be coming from. Set a breakpoint and step through your code line by line and examine the data at every step. You don't fix issues like this by reading the code. You execute the code and watch it in action, particularly the data it is using as it executes. There's a wealth of information provided by the debugger. You should make use of it to find bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing a lot of work manipulating the string that's causing you bugs. I think it would be easier to go with `Regex` to solve this.

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Copy string to format from clipboard
    Dim strClipText As String = Clipboard.GetText
    Dim regex = New Regex("-{0,1}\d+(\.\d+|)")
    Dim latlon = String.Join(" ", regex.Matches(strClipText).OfType(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value))
    Clipboard.Clear()
    My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(latlon)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with using regex. Something new to add to my toolbox :)

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that you're never replacing the carriage return.

Don't forget that these constants turn into actual ASCII characters or combinations of ASCII characters

- vbCr == Chr(13)
- vbLf == Chr(10)
- vbCrLf == Chr(13) + Char(10)
- vbNewLine == Chr(13) + Char(10)

Now, in your code, you're doing this:

```
strClipText = Replace(strClipText, vbLf, "")
strClipText = Replace(strClipText, vbCrLf, "")
strClipText = Replace(strClipText, vbNewLine, "")
```

Which does these three things:

1. Replace Chr(10) with an empty string
2. Replace Chr(13)+Char(10) with an empty string
3. Replace Chr(13)+Char(10) with an empty string

Thus, you're never getting rid of the Chr(13) which will sometimes show as a new line. Because, even if the lines begin life as Char(13) + Char(10) (vbCrLf) when you replace vbLf with an empty string, you're breaking up the Char(13) + Char(10).

Do something like this instead:

```
strClipText = Replace(strClipText, vbCrLf, "")
strClipText = Replace(strClipText, vbNewLine, "")
strClipText = Replace(strClipText, vbCR, "")
strClipText = Replace(strClipText, vbLf, "")
```

Comment: In case you you have a mistery character you can start from discarding everything that is not number/decimal point/sign and replace everything else with a space. Effectively it is a simple regex...